# Passing array parameters from jquery to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have any insight on what's going on here?  Here is my clientside jquery 1.4.1 code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PrintBOL/Print",
    data: [1, 2, 3],
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(xmlHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
        console.debug(xmlHttpRequest)
    },
    success: function(serverReply) {
        console.debug("OK")
        console.debug(serverReply)
    }
})
```

Here is my server-side method signature:

```
public ActionResult Print(int[] ids)
```

The ids parameter always comes across as null.

Any ideas?

By the way I make sure I invoke this at the top of the page:

```
 jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
```

UPDATE: See comments in Steven's answer below for resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

change:

```
data: [1, 2, 3],
```

to

```
data: {"ids": [1, 2, 3]},
```

Comment: does the Print Action have the POST attribute [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]?

Comment: remove contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" and dataType: "json".  JSON is the default for jQuery.  Also, root your url: url: "/PrintBOL/Print".

Comment: Removing contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", did it!  WTF?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
data: { "ids[0]": 1, "ids[1]": 2, "ids[2]": 3},
```

Comment: hmm, does var ids = [1,2,3]; JSON.stringify(ids) work?  How do I get that serialization automatically?

Comment: Odd I just tried this - data: {"ids[0]": 1, "ids[1]": 2}, and it still came accross as null

Comment: Try changing the param to `IEnumerable<int> ids` -- that's how I do it.

Comment: still nothing!  How do I even go about debugging whats going wrong here?

Comment: Look at the data you're sending in Firebug's Net panel or Fiddler. If you still can't figure it out, add the form data to your question.

Comment: The following is the contents of my POST as reported by firebug: ids%5B0%5D=1&ids%5B1%5D=2&ids%5B2%5D=3

Comment: When I do it @Steven's way my POST is: ids=1&ids=2&ids=3 - neither works

Comment: Try it in a do-nothing, new MVC project. This should work. Something else is going on, here.